# Which packages to write API documentations?

Tags: packages

Do exist packages suited to write API documentation ?

I would like to write a documentation in latex for a python library (actually, it's for a workshop, and the document is a normal latex document. I jut need to be able to add some code documentation entries here and there, and sphynx or doxygen are not suited for that). Thus I would need some package that would standardise displaying the class, method and function names, and also the parameters, their type and return type, with the ability to cross-reference other functions.

Google definitively failed to help me redirecting most of my tries to "documentation for package [...]"...

I could write it myself, but we live in a world where 99% of the things you could do yourself has already been done better by someone else. Thus here this question to people more capable than google I hope !

Comment: Searching around a bit it looks like Sphinx can generate LaTeX too...

Comment: I don't want to generate, I want to write my latex document normally without dealing with sphynx... Just asking if some package defines macro to have a nice looking documentation entry... I tried to edit the question to clarify

Comment: Ctan api, entered into google leads to package rest-api, which is part of this category: https://ctan.org/topic/program-doc . Entering similar search terms here and under Tags should give you a clue, what,s available ;-)

Comment: So if I can't find what I need at these links, I should infer such package does not exit yet ?

Comment: That would be my conclusion. But you never know, some seasoned specialist here might know a way for you. / I'd like to leave it there for now, as this site isn't intended for discussions, according to its rules.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is the `docmfp` package, which is an extension to the `doc` package, for documenting general non-LaTeX code.